# Polygon with vertex from a set of point

Tags: geometry, polygon

how can i make a polygon from given set of point.

possible polygon :

[image: possibility 1]
[image: possibility 2]

invalid polygon :

[image: self intersecting]

the polygon must be not self intersecting.

i have been thinking about sorting the point based on one point, but it seems it's not valid for some case.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, so:

1. Find a convex hull H of given points
2. For each point P not in hull, find the nearest edge HiHi+1 of the hull, and replace it with edges HiP and PHi+1.
3. If two points has the same nearest edge, tie them

[image: Example]